# Playing sound when app loads

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, audio

trying to play a sound when app loads

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    //sleep(2);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"austinpowers", CFSTR("wav"), NULL); 

    if (soundFileURLRef) {
        CFStringRef url = CFURLGetString(soundFileURLRef);
    }
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);



    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

it plays the sound, but only when the loading wallpaper (default.png) has gone.
if someone can help me, or point me in the right direction

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use Default.png, but create your custom splash screen view controller where you can display your image and play sound.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved for me by doing the following in the AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   NSURL *clip = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"intro" withExtension:@"caf"];
   self.startupPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clip error:NULL];
   [self.startupPlayer play]; 

}
```

This may work for you as well.